# Qooxdoo - available locales not present

Tags: internationalization, qooxdoo

The statement

```
qx.locale.Manager.getInstance().getAvailableLocales()
```

returns only de if I set LOCALES to "en", "de", or nothing if I set LOCALES in config.json to "en" only.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You have to re-run generate.py if you change the value of LOCALES in config.json. Did you do that?!
2. Are you using the `packages/i18n-with-boot` key in the configuration of your app? If it is set to `false`, locale data will be generated in dedicated parts which have to be loaded explicitly with `qx.io.PartLoader`. `getAvailableLocales` will only return those locales that have been loaded.

Comment: Thank you. @#1: I did that (a lot of times), @#2: I am using this configuration key, and loading it with the Partloader works now perfectly.